# angular2: ngOnChanges not called but display changed rightly

Tags: angular

My component has an mutable object input. When property of object changed,`ngOnChanges` of component is not called.It's easily understand.But the it's display changed rightly.

My component `hero-card`:

```
export class HeroCardComponent  implements OnChanges , DoCheck {
    @Input()
    Hero: Hero;
    @Input()
    Title: string;
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        for (const propName in changes) {
            const chng = changes[propName];
            const cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
            const prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
            console.log(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
        }
    }

}
```

It's template:

```
{{Title}}<br>
Hero title : {{Hero.title}}<br>
Hero name : {{Hero.name}}<br>
```

I changed hero.name in an input which has an two-way binding with hero.name.

Could Angular really checked the change?

The display changed seems it checked the change even in mutable object.Yeah , great!

But `ngOnChanges` is not called. It seemed that angular not checked the change. May be it only reset all of the view no matter change or not.

Who can tell me the truth?Thanks!

Comment: title is a property of hero not an input

Comment: yeah, "title" and "name" are properties of  hero object . Hero object is the input

Comment: so how do you expect ngOnChanges for title? it works only with input

Comment: Did you read documentation? `Angular only calls the hook when the value of the input property changes. The value of the hero property is the reference to the hero object. Angular doesn't care that the hero's own name property changed. The hero object reference didn't change so, from Angular's perspective, there is no change to report!` https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges You're looking for `ngDoCheck` hook

Comment: I wonder if Angular checked the change in the mutable object.

Comment: https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c#cf32 `Angular has to be conservative and run all the checks every single time because the JavaScript language does not give us object mutation guarantees.`

Comment: @yurzui You mean Angular do not find the change , right? But why the display changed rightly?

Comment: If you don't use OnPush and if you don't detach ChangeDetector then Angular will update view. It doesn't matter whether the ngOnChanges method has been called or not. If you want to find changes in this case then use `ngDoCheck` https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck

Comment: Angular didn't find change.But Angular refresh view form input data every time.Right?

Comment: Right. Angular will perform updating view

Comment: @ZebulonLi, _from input data_ - not from input data, from component properties. Input data is irrelevant when Angular runs change detection for `HeroCardComponent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular tracks input bindings by reference, and since the reference to `Hero` object hasn't changed `ngOnChanges` is not triggered. It means that Angular hasn't detected **change for** the `Hero` object **reference**. And this check for changes is actually performed **when** Angular **checks parent component**, not `HeroCardComponent`.

However, in template you use the following:

```
Hero name : {{Hero.name}}<br>
```

which means that everytime Angular runs change detection for the `HeroCardComponent` component it has to check whether `Hero.name` is changed. It is not related really related to the check of `Hero` object reference. I happens when Angular **runs change detection for the `HeroCardComponent` component**. If the expression used in DOM evaluates to a different value, it updates the dom. You can read more about updating the DOM in the [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d).

If you want to track object mutations yourself you can use ngDoCheck lifecycle hook. It's explained in depth in the article [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5).

For more information on change detection you should read:

- [Angular’s $digest is reborn in the newer version of Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e)
- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Comment: 1.DOM updates checking is irrelevant with ngOnChanges checking , it's two     process in change detection 2. every {{}} will have a binding object. 3. The binding object check dirty every change detection  4.binding object help to DOM updates .   Right?

Comment: @ZebulonLi, 1. It's one process, but performed for different components - ngOnChanges when checking parent, DOM update when checking child. 
Read two articles I linked in the answer. 2. For every `{{}}` a code will be generated inside the `updateRenderer` function. 3. Yes, the `updatedRenderer` function is called on every check. 4. The actual DOM update is not peformed by `updateRenderer` - that's pretty complicated as you probably guessed from the article.